# Visualize autocorrelation with python in multiple timeseries one dataset

Tags: regression, visualization, statsmodels, autocorrelation

**Background**

Performing multiple linear regression analysis on dataset containing 21 time-series of 4 data points. Each data points represents 9 variables which could describe a value. The 21 data points are for hydrological catchments.

R² adjusted is not decreasing rapidly after adding more variables.

**Problem statement**

Since the 4 data points are a static window of a longer time-series I am thinking autocorrelation between the data-points is the problem.

**Question**

How to visualize or estimate if there is autocorrelation inside the different time-series? Preferably with stats-models.

**What I have tried:**

[image]

I think ACF of the residuals is not working since I have 21 time-series.